# Symonfy2 I have a User Entity which requires to have a SkillSet Entity

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

In my work I have been assigned to make a shift managing web app.

I have based my code on the OpenSkedge, but now I require that each user has a skill set and a number associated with it. Each user has a set of skills which also have a number associated with from 1 to 3.

This project is based on the Symfony2 framework and MySQL database.

A user has a some files:

1. User.php
2. UserRespository.php
3. UserType.php
4. UserContoller.php

Which corresponds to a database table os_user;

To resolve the skill set problem, I have made files on my own which would generate a a new table os_skillset;

```
create table os_skillset ( id int(6) , skillset varchar(255), skill_set_number int(6));
```

The first file is to create the entity, SkillSet.php

```
<?php
// src/OpenSkedge/AppBundle/Entity/SkillSet.php
namespace OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="skillset")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity\SkillSetRepository")
 */
class SkillSet 
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $skillSet;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $skillNumber;


    public function __construct(){
        $this-> skillset = ArrayCollection();

    }
    public function getid();
    {
        return $this -> id;
    }

    public function getSkillset();
    {
        return $this -> skillSet;
    }

    public function getSkillnumber();
    {
        return $this -> skillNumber;
    }

    public fucntion setid($uid){
         $this -> id = $uid
         return $this;

    }
    public function setSkillset($skills){
         $this-> skillSet = $skillset;
         return $this;
    }
    public function setSkillnumber($nm){
         $this -> skillNumber = $nm;
         return $this;
    }


}
```

The second file is the Contoller file, SkillSetController.php

```
<?php

namespace OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

use OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity\Skillset;
use OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity\Clock;
use OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

use Pagerfanta\Pagerfanta;
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\DoctrineORMAdapter;
use Pagerfanta\Adapter\DoctrineCollectionAdapter;


class SkillSetContoller extends Controller{

    public function creatAction($id,$skillset,$skillNumber){

            $sid = new Skillset();
            $sid->setid($id);
            $sid->setSkillset($skillset);
            $sid->setSkillnumber($skillNumber);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $entityManager->persist($product);

            $entityManager->flush();

    }
    public function showAction($id){
        $sid = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(SetSkill::class)->findByid($id)

        if (!$sid) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No skill set  found for user with id '.$id
        );
    }


}
```

Third file, SkillSetRepository.php:

```
<?php
// src/OpenSkedge/AppBundle/Entity/SkillSetRepository.php

namespace OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

class SkillSetRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
        public function findByid($id){
            return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT u from AppBundle:SkillSet u where u.id = :id'
                )
            ->getResult();
        }

}
```

In the user form I have added a new wigdet:
    ->add('skillset','text')

The following error is shown:
**Neither the property "skillset" nor one of the methods "getSkillset()", "skillset()", "isSkillset()", "hasSkillset()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Entity\User".**

My question is how do I connect all of this information so in the user form I am able to view and edit each skill set a user has?

A user could have many skill sets and each of them will be assigned a number

Comment: Update:  According to https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/embedded.html got an error Could not load type "OpenSkedge\AppBundle\Form\SkillSetType"

Comment: According to your code it looks like you have skill set master and user master . One user can have multiple skill and one skill also associated with mutliple user so you have to go with ManyToMany relationship.  I would suggest to read doctrine ManytoMany relation so you will get an idea about how it works. If you still have issue I am open to help :)